# SQL Join Multiple table query

Tags: c#, sql, join

I wrote following code:

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("Select City.City, Company.Company,Emp_Depart.Department,Emp_Name.Uname from Emp_Name INNER join Emp_Name on" +
            "Emp_Name.Id=Emp_Depart.Id Emp_Name.Id=Company.Id Emp_Name.Id=City.Id where Emp_Name.Id=" + txtId.Text);
 cmd.Connection = con;
 da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
 txtName .Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim();
```

I am getting following error

Additional information: `Incorrect syntax near '.'.`

I am newbie for Joins 
Please help me out...

Comment: What is the value of txtId.Text

Comment: Please correct your query. After Inner join, you should use equal to operator between only two columns or you should use And/OR operator in between. You have multiple column comparision after ON.

Answer (score 2):

You missed `And operator` in `join condition`

```
SELECT CITY.CITY,
       COMPANY.COMPANY,
       EMP_DEPART.DEPARTMENT,
       EMP_NAME.UNAME
FROM   EMP_NAME
       INNER JOIN EMP_DEPART
               ON EMP_NAME.ID = EMP_DEPART.ID
       INNER JOIN COMPANY
         ON EMP_NAME.ID = COMPANY.ID
       INNER JOIN CITY
         ON EMP_NAME.ID = CITY.ID 
WHERE EMP_NAME.ID =+ TXTID.TEXT
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep,
But I am getting another error
Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Comment: I used same code what you posted and tried to execute but it is showing error " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'".

Comment: @surya You were missing some tables in join. updated check now.

Comment: Thank you so much worked for me now learned new thing from you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AND` between multiple join conditions. Also, add a space after `EMP_name on`.